# Hockeyapp and Cocapods - app crashes

Tags: nativescript, hockeyapp

I'm using Nativescript version 4.0 and i see again that, if i've use any plugin that is build with cocapods, when app is installed via Hockeyapp, will crash when navigating to this view. 
This is not happening on my local builds, on emulators or real device with app installed via Xcode.
Does anybody has any ideas, why is this happening?

Cheeers.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the build from HockeyApp to your machine and install it locally through Xcode?
Please also provide a fully symbolicate crash report of the crash, otherwise it's near impossible to tell what's going on.

Comment: Hi @LukasSpieß,
i think it's related on how app is code signed etc. I had lots of certs, provisional profiles etc... I've cleaned most of them, that do build with working certs, and i see no issues now.

Comment: Great! Just wanted to make you aware that using an ad-hoc installation mechanism like the one HockeyApp provides does not change the binary itself and therefore can't be the root issue :)

Comment: Hi, i've figured this out - the problem was that i was building as Debug, when i'm building an app as release, no issues. Cheers.